# Line Chart on top of Stacked Column Chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, stacked-chart, rdl, cumulative-line-chart

I am new at chart design in SSRS, I wanted to display line chart on top of Stacked Column chart .
I can easily get that with simple/single column chart. But I can not find a way to display a Line chart on top of a stacked column chart. I have added images for both simple and stacked chart.
How can I implement line chart on top of stacked chart? Or Is it possible the way I want to display in SSRS ? Thanks in advance.

[Image of line chart on top of simple column chart with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k2gs.jpg)

[Image of stacked Column chart in which I want to add line chart on top of it like simple column chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN2YW.jpg)

Comment: Add a new group for the values and then right-click on it and `Change Chart Type` and set it to Line chart.

Comment: Actually I Have done it successfully. Thanks anyway :)